# Correct way to render a modules output through a template?

Tags: theming

I usually do exclusively functionality on a site, and as such I'm familiar with php and Drupals APIs, but I'm mostly lost in the theming layers.

I find myself with these pieces of code, that "work", but doesn't look quite right to me.

```
// ------ Actual USE of #theme -------
$block->content = array(
  '#theme' => 'MODULE_more_information',
  'dataA' => $dataA,
  'dataB' => $dataB,
  'dataC' => $dataC,
);  
return $block;

// ------ hook_theme to attach the #theme to a template -------
function HOOK_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $base = array(
    'render element' => 'element',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'HOOK') . '/templates',
  );
  $theme = array(
    'MODULE_more_information' => array(
      'template' => 'MODULE-more-information',
    ) + $base,
  );
  return $theme;
}

// ------ Actual template -------
<?php 
extract($element);
?>

<div class="content">
  <h1><?php print $dataA ?></h1>
  <h1><?php print $dataB ?></h1>
  <h1><?php print $dataC ?></h1>
</div>
```

What gives me the idea that something is amiss is that the author manually runs `extract()`, which I've never seen a template do before.

Canonical examples of how to do this "right"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be honest, aside from the use of `extract()` (which is obviously [bad](http://php.dzone.com/news/php-bad-practice-use-extract) in and of itself), I think the code is perfectly valid, and respectful of Drupal's processes/conventions.

There are two different ways to pass variables to theme functions in Drupal 7, both provided as an argument to a theme definition in `hook_theme()`. They are `variables` and `render element`.

I can't possibly explain the difference between these two better than the [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) docs:

> Use 'render element' if you are theming a single element or element tree composed of elements, such as a form array, a page array, or a single checkbox element.
>
> Use 'variables' if your theme implementation is intended to be called directly through theme() and has multiple arguments for the data and style; in this case, the variables not supplied by the calling function will be given default values and passed to the template or theme function.

In your case you're theming a render array, rather than calling `theme()` directly, so `render element` is the one to use.

When you use a `#theme` property on a render array, the entire element (in your case `$block['content']`) is passed through to the theme function/template file. The name of the variable that you have access to in the template file is the name you have given to `render element` in the `hook_theme()` definition.

So if your `hook_theme()` defines `'render element' => 'my_lovely_var'`, you'll have access to the render array as `$my_lovely_var` in the template file.

I suspect that the author of your code was just taking a small shortcut so he/she didn't have to access the `$element` array directly with code. Without the use of `extract()` the template file would/should have looked like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <h1><?php print $element['dataA'] ?></h1>
  <h1><?php print $element['dataB'] ?></h1>
  <h1><?php print $element['dataC'] ?></h1>
</div>
```

Just for posterity, this is the same code re-written to make use of `variables` instead:

The same code using `variables` would look like this:

```
// ------ Actual USE of #theme -------
$args = array('dataA' => $dataA, 'dataB' => $dataB, 'dataC' => $dataC);
$block->content = array(
  '#markup' => theme('MODULE_more_information', $args)
);
return $block;

// ------ hook_theme to attach the #theme to a template -------
function HOOK_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'MODULE_more_information' => array(
      'template' => 'MODULE-more-information',
      'variables' => array('dataA' => '', 'dataB' => '', 'dataC' => ''),
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'HOOK') . '/templates'
    )
  );
}

// ------ Actual template -------
<div class="content">
  <h1><?php print $dataA ?></h1>
  <h1><?php print $dataB ?></h1>
  <h1><?php print $dataC ?></h1>
</div>
```

You could even use the following, slightly different, method to build up the block content when using `variables`:

```
$block->content = array(
  '#theme' => 'MODULE_more_information',
  '#dataA' => $dataA,
  '#dataB' => $dataB,
  '#dataC' => $dataC,
);
return $block;
```

This second method makes the block more re-usable as the theme function hasn't already been called, and other parts of the system can still alter the individual elements of the block.

Comment: Cool, thanks :) When _would_ it be appropriate to use a `render element`? What is it?